# Передача данных между классами в NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ооп, xmpp, discord-api

Начал изучать Node JS и поставил для себя задачу: реализовать транспортный бот `irc<->jabber<->discord`. С получением потоков чата проблем не возникло, но ступор настал в момент, когда нужно передавать сообщения между классами.

Например: при действии `discord.on('message')` класса `Discord` вызывать действие из класса `Jabber`.

Может кто-то подсказать, как правильно это реализовать (желательно с примером на моем коде).

***app.js***

```
const config = require('./config.json');
let Discord = require('./lib/discord');
let Jabber = require('./lib/jabber');

console.log("=============================");
if(config.discord.enable){
    const discord = new Discord(config.discord.token);
    discord.connect();
    discord.attachListeners();
}
if(config.jabber.enable){
    const jabber = new Jabber(config.jabber.jid, config.jabber.password, config.jabber.server, config.jabber.room_jid, config.jabber.room_nick);
    jabber.connect();
    jabber.attachListeners();
}
```

***/lib/jabber.js***

```
let xmpp = require('node-xmpp')

class Jabber{
    constructor(jid, password, server, conference, nick){
        this.jid = jid;
        this.password = password;
        this.server = server;
        this.conference = conference;
        this.nick = nick;
        console.log('=== Jabber Class Constructed');
    }

    connect(){
        this.jabber = new xmpp.Client({
            jid: this.jid+"@"+this.server+"/bot",
            password: this.password,
            reconnect: true
        });
        console.log('=== Jabber Connected');
    }

    attachListeners() {
        this.jabber.on('online', () => {
            this.jabber.send(new xmpp.Element('presence', { type: 'available' }).c('show').t('chat'));
            this.jabber.send(new xmpp.Element('presence', { to: this.conference+'/'+this.nick }).
                c('x', { xmlns: 'http://jabber.org/protocol/muc' })
            );
            setInterval(function() {
                this.jabber.send(' ');
            }, 30000);
            console.log("=== Jabber Joined to Room");
        });

        this.jabber.on('stanza', (stanza) => {
            if (stanza.attrs.type == 'error') {
                console.log('[error] ' + stanza);
                return;
            }
            if (!stanza.is('message') || !stanza.attrs.type == 'groupchat') {
                return;
            }

            if (stanza.attrs.from == this.conference+'/'+this.nick) {
                return;
            }

            let body = stanza.getChild('body');
            if (!body) {
                return;
            }
            let sender = stanza.attrs.from.toString().substring(this.conference.length+1);
            let message = body.getText();

            console.log("Jabber | "+ sender+": "+message);

        });
    }
}

module.exports = Jabber;
```

***/lib/discord.js***

```
let discord = require('discord.js');

class Discord{
    constructor(token){
        this.discordToken = token;
        this.discord = new discord.Client({ autoReconnect: true });
        console.log('=== Discord Class Constructed');
    }

    connect(){
        this.discord.login(this.discordToken);
        console.log('=== Discord Connected');
    }

    attachListeners() {
        this.discord.on('ready', () => {
            console.log('=== Discord Joined to Server');
        });

        this.discord.on('error', (error) => {
            console.log('Received error event from Discord', error);
        });

        this.discord.on('warn', (warning) => {
            console.log('Received warn event from Discord', warning);
        });

        this.discord.on('message', (msg) => {
            console.log(`Discord | ${msg.author.username} ${msg.content}`);
        });

    }
}

module.exports = Discord;
```

Код на гите для удобства: https://github.com/DiWorm/NodeJS-Bot.

Comment: Вставляйте код прямо в сообщение, а не ссылайтесь на внешние ресурсы. Сообщения должны быть самодостаточными, ссылки могут служить только дополнением.

Comment: да и у вас там совсем нет ООП.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman в этом то и ступор, в отсутствии понимания -- как его правильно реализовать в Ноде. Через var someName = function(){} или же через prototype.. Хорошо, добавлю код в текст.

Comment: так вы начните не с node.js, а с более простых вещей. в сети много примеров ОО подхода для JS.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman открыта куча вкладок по ОО и JS, перечитал тонну информации, не понимаю -- с этим и пришел сюда. Возможно упускаю какую-то простую мелочь, т.к. nodejs кардинально отличается от того, чем пользовался до этого.

Comment: задайте конкретный вопрос, покажите свое решение. в node.js (да в JS в целом) не обязательно использовать ОО подход.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman конкретный вопрос задан — как передавать информацию между методами. Я объявил 2 метода: jabber и discord , теперь задача стоит: при действии client.on('message') , например discord вызывать некую функцию которая бы отправляла информацию в метод jabber

Comment: это не методы, а функции. вы описали две функции которые вызываются при возникновении события. добавьте ваши уточнения в сам вопрос.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman переписал код, дополнил тему.

Comment: @larrymacbarry в данном случае - я не хочу использовать БД, а хочу делать "на лету". Пытаюсь понять как при получении сообщения (эвент "on") использовать функцию отправки из другого класса. В любом случае мне это будет нужно чтобы завернуть все потоки в 1 буфер и из него уже отправлять данные куда-нужно и как нужно..

Comment: Ниже ответ. А буффер в ноде или, как вы его называете "поток" (на самом деле нет) - это объект req, полученный обработчиком роута. То есть, при каждом запросе в ноде создается объект req, в котором можно хранить данные, сообщения и тд. Этот объект по очереди можно обрабатывать разными модулями.

Comment: @larrymacbarry звучит интересно, можно ссылочку - где почитать можно об этом подробнее?

Comment: Сказанное мной относится к модулю Express, чтобы избежать путанницы.
Очень много документации, даже на русском, а вот про объекты статья: http://www.murvinlai.com/req-and-res-in-nodejs.html
А от себя я написал свою интерпритацию накопленного опыта. Вы можете просто законсолить req при запросе и посмотреть, что там внутри. Многие модули, такие, как passport.js используют этот объект.

Comment: @larrymacbarry спасибо за информацию, посмотрим, что еще народ скажет. Но пока ваша интерпритация нравится, правда пока не понял можно ли это использовать с несколькими модулями одновременно, но это дело наживное :)

Comment: function Discord(otherModule, anotherOne, onemoreModule, ...){

попробуйте, в некоторых случаях по-другому и не получится сделать никак.

Comment: Наследуйте EventEmitter и будет вам счастье

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напишу псевдокод, так как не секу в ваших модулях, но передавать объект другого модуля можно напрямую, включив их аргумент. Не используйте классы ,если не понимаете, как они работают, функции отлично работают для таких вещей.

```
let discord = require('discord.js');

function Discord(otherModule){
   ....
   otherModule.methodOfOtherModule()
}

module.exports = Discord(otherModule);
```

В файле контроллера:

```
var otherModule = require('otherModule.js');
var discord = require('/lib/discord.js')(otherModule)
```

Так вы передадите объект модуля, со всеми его методами. Делал для сокета, мангуса и других модулей, но метод универсальный.